# Two radio Buttons getting selected in android

Tags: android

I know that many answers will be available in internet but none of them seems to work for me.

I have two radio buttons in my layout, i want only one to be get selected at a time. I dont use radiogroup in layout. I tried using .setChecked condition but it doesn't give me solution

```
     <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                            <RadioButton
                                android:id="@+id/RadioButtontop"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/text_weekOff" />

                        </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="2dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/text_weekOff" />

                    </LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: are you sure you don't want to use RadioGroups? they can probably solve this problem. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you need to add those `RadioButtons` in a `RadioGroup`. In this way you can achieve what you want.

What have you tried, to use `setChecked()` method, works only with `CheckBoxes`. In which you can set a single checkbox `setChecked(true)` while all the others `setChecked(flase)`.

In the case of `RadioButtons`, you need to use a `RadioGroup`. It will solve your problem for sure. In code should look like this:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FirstRadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/firstRadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SecondRadioButton"
            android:id="@+id/secondRadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Wrap your `RadioButtons` with `RadioGroup` to get checked single `RadioButton` at once.

**2.** Instead of using `TextView`, you can set text to `RadioButton` using attribute `android:text="@string/text_weekOff"`.

**Try this:**

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_weekOff" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text_weekOff" />
</RadioGroup>
```